# Can I change the name of my map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My map is called `map_0`, which isn't that great. Can I change it?

[image: map_0]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now you can change the maps using an anvil. It requires levels to rename the map however.

Comment: Pro tip: rename your map _before_ making copies, or else you will have to rename each copy.

Comment: though this is the correct answer now, but in 2011, when this question was asked, the answer is no.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't. When you create a map, its name becomes map_x, where "x" is an incremental id.

Comment: Should  be relatively easy to mod in, though.

Answer (score -2):

just go in singleplayer worlds menu then click on the world on the bottom left corner theres a button called rename use that! Thanks hope i helped